# .htaccess redirect only if parameter exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

hello guys i want write `htaccess` file that make access denied for this url `localhost/img/pic.gif` else if i get something like this `localhost/img/pic.gif?var=welcome` will redirect me to another page accept any parameter i don't need to test is get number or letter
it's that possible to do that with `htaccess` file all i know is this line :

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /pic.gif
 RewriteRule logo.gif  localhost/myproject
```

thank you !

Comment: Is your webserver using backslashes as directory separate r ? or maybe you are on windows  . `localhost\img\pic.gif` and `localhost/img/pic.gif` are two different urls .

Comment: i'm in windows yeah i write it wrong  wrong url sorry with this `/`

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404 /pic.gif` tells server to return a 404 error for all uris ending with `pic.gif` . Do you get a 404 error when you go to `example.com/pic.gif` ?

Comment: yeah i know that wrong i don't know what i should write sir . as i tell you i need to get access denied for url without parameter and when i get some parameter like this `pic.gif?var=welcome` redirect me

Comment: All i need if  after the url `localhost/img/pic.gif?` some parameter anything redirect me to index page else  if the url `localhost/img/pic.gif` denied the access